# Rails "has_many" association: "collection=" doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Invoice has many invoice entries:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_entries, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :date
end

class InvoiceEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  validates_presence_of :description
end
```

Assume we have a single invoice in the database:

```
id: 1
date: '2013-06-16'
```

and it has two invoice entries:

```
id: 10                           id: 11
invoice_id: 1                    invoice_id: 1
description: 'do A'              description: 'do C'
```

Now, I have the new invoice entries:

```
id: 10                               
description: 'do B'              description: 'do D'

(Existing invoice entry          (New invoice entry
 with updated description)        without id)
```

I would like the invoice to have only these new invoice entries (this means that invoice entry with `id=11` should be deleted).

`invoice.invoice_entries = new_invoice_entries` seems to do half of the work. It removes the invoice entry with `id=11`, creates a new invoice entry with description `'Do D'`, **but it doesn't update the description of invoice entry with `id=10` from `'Do A'` to `'Do B'`**. I guess that when Rails sees an existing `id` in `new_invoice_entries`, it totally ignores it. Is that true? If yes, what is the rationale behind this?

My full code is below. How would you fix this issue? (I use Rails 4, in case it simplifies the code.)

---

```
# PATCH/PUT /api/invoices/5
def update
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  errors = []

  # Invoice entries
  invoice_entries_params = params[:invoice_entries] || []
  invoice_entries = []

  for invoice_entry_params in invoice_entries_params
    if invoice_entry_params[:id].nil?
      invoice_entry = InvoiceEntry.new(invoice_entry_params)
      errors << invoice_entry.errors.messages.values if not invoice_entry.valid?
    else
      invoice_entry = InvoiceEntry.find_by_id(invoice_entry_params[:id])

      if invoice_entry.nil?
        errors << "Couldn't find invoice entry with id = #{invoice_entry_params[:id]}"
      else
        invoice_entry.assign_attributes(invoice_entry_params)
        errors << invoice_entry.errors.messages.values if not invoice_entry.valid?
      end
    end

    invoice_entries << invoice_entry
  end

  # Invoice
  @invoice.assign_attributes(date: params[:date])

  errors << @invoice.errors.messages.values if not @invoice.valid?

  if errors.empty?
    # Save everything
    @invoice.invoice_entries = invoice_entries
    @invoice.save

    head :no_content
  else
    render json: errors.flatten, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change not only the association but also the attributes of the associated objects, you have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_entries, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :date
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_entries, allow_destroy: true
end
```

There's a [railscast episode 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) on how to build dynamic nested forms using `nested_attributes`.

Addendum:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` expects attributes for the nested models in a nested hash, i.e.:

```
invoice_params={"date" => '2013-06-16', 
  "invoice_entries_attributes" => [
    {"description" => "do A"},
    {"description" => "do B"}]
}

invoice= Invoice.new(invoice_params)
invoice.save
```

the `save` saves `invoice` and two `invoice_items`.

Now

```
invoice=Invoice.find(1)
invoice_params={
  "invoice_entries_attributes" => [
    {"description" => "do A"},
    {"description" => "do C"}]
}
invoice.update_attributes(invoice_params)
```

deletes the item `do B` and adds the item `do C`.

`form_fields` can be used to create forms that result in exaclty that kind of nested hashes.
For details see the railscast.

Comment: I tried to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_entries`, but it doesn't make any difference. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17142290/247243

Answer (score 0):

Try using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. This would clean up a lot of your code! Here is a example:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_entries, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :date
  attr_accessible :invoice_entries_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_entries, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

In the view can you then use `fields_for` (`simple_fields_for` with simple form, and `semantic_fields_for` with formtastic if you use one of these gems).

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |invoice_form| %>
  <%= invoice_form.fields_for :invoice_entries do |invoice_entry_form| %>
    <%= invoice_entry_form.text_field :description %>
    <%= invoice_entry_form.check_box :_destroy %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In you controller can you now refactor down to the basics:

```
# PATCH/PUT /api/invoices/5
def update
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice]) # This also saves all associated invoice entries, and destroy all that is marked for destruction.
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: @invoice.errors.flatten, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

You can read more about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Or you can watch this railscast about nested models: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: Adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_entries` doesn't help. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17142290/247243