# Rails: Data not getting saved with assign_attributes in before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, update-attributes, before-save

I am doing an update in *before_save* as below:

```
has_many :things

before_save :set_things

def set_things
  things = all_things.map do |t|
    t.assign_attributes(attrs) 
    t
  end
  self.things = things
end
```

When i save the object as **t.save!** , the objects has updated attributes, but once reloaded its going back to old value, so updation is not persisting. If i use, t.update_attributes it is working fine, but isnt *assign_attributes* supposed to persist on save? Why isnt it working ?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? In versions before 5, returning a non-truthy value from a callback can cancel the current operation being made (like a save for example). If you're running a version below 5 try adding `true` at the bottom of the callback.

Comment: Assign_attributes it should persist after save. There is something happening inside this callback.

Have you ever tried to put a constant value in the callback just to see if it was saved?

Something like removing all the code and putting only `self.things = [Thing.new()]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved. Since, i was updating an existing record, assign_attribute wasnt updating attributes. Only new record will be updated accroding to this:
[Rails: Why “collection=” doesn't update records with existing id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142290/rails-why-collection-doesnt-update-records-with-existing-id)